# Templates to use multiple time within page?

Tags: templates

New to WP, so this may be a newbie question.

My page will consist of structured data:
     Movie title, Movie release date, Movie Poster Image filename.

On mediawiki, my page might look something like this:

```
{{movie-template|Gone With the Wind|1939|gwtw.jpg}}
{{movie-template|Citizen Kane|1941|ck.jpg}}
{{movie-template|Star Wars|1977|sw.jpg}}
```

How do I do this in wordpress?

Comment: Have you already installed WordPress and tried to create a post?

Comment: Yes.    I have wordpress installed, up and running, I have working pages with content that display correct.

Comment: Looks you are ready to create posts with movie title, release date e.g. as tag, category or custom field and poster as attachment. Read "[New To WordPress - Where to Start](https://codex.wordpress.org/New_To_WordPress_-_Where_to_Start)" before.

Comment: Well, i'm looking for templates I can use multiple times within a Page.   If my actual implementation were that simple, I could uses Posts, but I intentionally oversimplified to make the question a little easier to ask.

Comment: If your use case is not possible with Posts, you might need [Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) as the starting point. You also need to look up Meta boxes and Page template to build up any structure that you want.

Comment: @Random This site about development of such themes (templates), plugins or additional functionality. It is written in the site name.  So, when you've made a theme you can ask for the problem you've stuck in. But this site is not the right place to ask where to get themes, to ask somebody to develop the theme for you or to hire a WordPress guru.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are trying to do this within a page or post, you could make a shortcode out of it.

`[movie-template title="Gone With the Wind" date="1939" image="gwtw.jpg"]
[movie-template title="Citizen Kane" date="1941" image="ck.jpg"]
[movie-template title="Star Wars" date="1977" image="sw.jpg"]`

Then you need a little code, in your template's functions.php, or in a custom plugin:

`add_shortcode( 'movie-template', 'my_movie_listings' );
function my_movie_listings( $atts ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
      'foo_title' => 'title',
      'foo_date' => 'date',
      'foo_image' => 'image',
    ), $atts );
  // $atts['foo_title'] is your movie title
  // $atts['foo_date'] is your movie date
  // $atts['foo_image'] is your movie image
  $ret = "do something here with {$atts['foo_title']}";
  return $ret;
}`